# CSS "#id1 #id2" selector, why it is not same as only "#id2"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

See an example at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxwerv12/1/),

```
  #rightDiv a#id1match { left:60px;top:10px }
```

where the changes to `#id1match` or `a#id1match` destroys the layout.

---

My "invalid logic" here was: #id selector points to a unique ID in the document, so, the "id inside other thing" must be the same than "id"... And in this case the HTML always have both IDs, not change... The *inside selector* should not have any influence in the ID when both exists.

Comment: What if `a#id1match` is *not* within `#rightDiv`? Then `#rightDiv a#id1match` will not match. They don't mean the same thing. Even though an ID selector represents a unique element, it says nothing about *where* this unique element may appear in the document. But as mentioned in the answer, the real issue here is not structure, but specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [CSS Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

`#id1match` does correctly match your element. However that element also has the class `.region` which has a more specific selector of `#rightDiv .region`

So basically your styling is being overriden because when you remove `#rightDiv` the rule becomes less important. Look at your element in any developer tools and you can see what is happening.

[image: Styling]

Comment: I never think in "calculate the specificity" for an ID!  So, you show the correct clues, thanks a lot. Well, about "logic"... There are "no logic", only a game of maximum specificity scores ! :-)